# Django tastypie serializes DecimalField as json strings instead of numbers

Tags: django, json, tastypie

I have a `django` application with `tastypie`. One of the models in my app has a `DecimalField`. When I get a response from the API in `JSON` format, all the decimal fields appear as `strings` instead of `numbers`:

For example I get:

```
objects: [
    {
        id: "1",
        my_decimal_field: "84.54"
    }
```

instead of

```
objects: [
    {
        id: "1"
        my_decimal_field: 84.54
    }
```

This also happens with the id field.

¿Any thoughts?

Comment: I also have the same problem: decimal fields are returned as strings. You can call parseFloat at client level but it isn't very effective when writing a function called for every returned data. Any improvement about this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, JSON decodes to [double-precision floating point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), which causes a loss of precision. `Decimal` objects are encoded to `string` to maintain precision.

If you want to encode to JSON number format, you can use a `FloatField`.